# C# is there a problem with division?

Tags: c#

This is a piece of my code, it is called every second, after about 10 seconds the values start to become weird (see below):

```
double a;
double b;

for (int i = 0; i < currAC.Length; i++ )
{                 
    a = currAC[i];
    b = aveACValues[i];
    divisor = (a/b);
    Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString("N2") + "\t" + "b = " + b.ToString("N2"));
    Console.WriteLine("divisor = " + divisor);
    Console.WriteLine("a+b = " + (a+b));
}
```

and the output:

a = **-0.05**  **b = 0.00**

divisor = **41**

a+b = **-0.0524010372273268**

currAC and aveACValues are double[]

what on earth is going on???? The addition result is correct every time, but the division value is wrong, yet it is reading a and b correctly??

**EDIT: '41' is the value of the first calculation, ie when a = currAC[0], but this should not remain???**

Comment: You dividing by zero. God help you. I think it is an apporximation very close to zero. Then, .05/~0 would result in a reasonbly big number.

Comment: I don't get it. If b is 0.00, isn't this a division by zero?

Comment: No because its actually 0.00xxxxx ive rounded the Console.WriteLine to 2 decimal places

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(-0.05f / 0.00f);` displayed `-Infinity` for me

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `currAC` and `aveACValues` arrays?  (Or at least a few entries that can reproduce the problem?)

Comment: We need to see the declaration of divisor.

Comment: First off, it would go a lot easier if you actually provided a small, complete, *working* program that demonstrated the problem you're having; then people could analyze it rather than trying to guess. Second, the fact that you are calling a/b the *divisor* when it is in fact the *quotient* is very confusing. The *divisor* is b, the *dividend* is a, and a/b is the *quotient*.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted the question. It's so unclear noone can understand why you think the result looks wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if b == -0.001219512195122, then a/b==41, and a+b==-0.051219512195122 - so something *around* those areas (rounding etc) sounds feasible...

Also; note that for some arithmetic, it is possible it is using values that are still in registers. Registers may exhibit slightly different accuracy (and so give different results) than local variables.

Comment: Hey guys, you've misunderstood my problem- the problem is that the first division result is being remembered even though the loop finishes on the next run, its always 41 or whatever number was first....

Comment: @Tom - what makes you think that it isn't the right value? What I mean is - there are values a/b that would display those values to 2dp, and give that divisor.

Answer (score 0):

`double` can result in inprecise results, due to the specification (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(VS.71).aspx)). You might want to use `decimal` instead, it offers more precision.

Comment: hi, but does this answer why the value 41 is being remembered?

Comment: Not really, but we would need to know how divisor is defined.

Comment: I don't think the fact that he's using a base-2 floating-point number versus a base-10 floating point number makes any difference here.   `decimal` is really only "better" if you are interested in rounding your numbers to a certain number of base-10 representation digits.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the variables are declared as close to where they are used as is possible?

```
for (int i = 0; i < currAC.Length; i++ ) 
{                  
    double a = currAC[i]; 
    double b = aveACValues[i]; 
    double divisor = (a/b); 
    Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString("N2") + "\t" + "b = " + b.ToString("N2")); 
    Console.WriteLine("divisor = " + divisor.ToString()); 
    Console.WriteLine("a+b = " + (a+b).ToString()); 
}
```

This would ensure that you have a fresh "divisor" each time and will not be affected by other scopes.